# Java Number Randomizer is getting null as output

Tags: java, arrays, loops, null, output

In this program I've created a class called `ArrayExample` and created a random number to fill its elements and a `toString()` method with it. Why am I getting null as my output? The code has no errors from what it seems like.  :

```
public class arran {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayExample[] no1 = new ArrayExample[5];
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(no1));
    }

    public class ArrayExample {
        int[] array;

        ArrayExample(int len) {
            array = new int[len];
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                array[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(array.length);
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                sb.append(array[i]);

            }
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(array.length); error might be there array isn't initialized yet probably

Comment: You create `new ArrayExample[5]`, but you don't put anything in it. That's why it just contains `null` five times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating `ArrayExample[5]`, which is an *array* of five `ArrayExample` objects, and not a single `ArrayExample` with a constructor argument of `5`.  It looks like your intent was to invoke the constructor `ArrayExample(int len)`, but it's never called.

Try this, instead:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayExample no1 = new ArrayExample(5); // Invokes the constructor you wrote
        System.out.println(no1.toString()); // Uses the toString method your wrote
    }
```

Make your inner class static so it can be accessed by your main method:

```
public static class ArrayExample {
```

And fix your `.toString()` method:

```
  public String toString() {
    return Arrays.toString(array);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this code:

```
ArrayExample[] no1 = new ArrayExample[5];
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(no1));
```

This declares an array of a certain type (`ArrayExample`), and a certain length (5), but it doesn't do anything else. That first line results in a variable reference `no1` containing five null values. That's what you see when you print it out.

```
[null, null, null, null, null]
```

Here's another example, but using `Object` to highlight that the code isn't doing anything other than creating an empty array and printing the null values.

```
Object[] no2 = new Object[5];
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(no2));
```

This code has the same output:

```
[null, null, null, null, null]
```

Here is code that will initialize the array (like you already were doing), then create a new instance of `ArrayExample` and save it at each array element. (I also moved `ArrayExample` out of the main class definition so that it compiles).

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayExample[] no1 = new ArrayExample[5];

        no1[0] = new ArrayExample(10);
        no1[1] = new ArrayExample(10);
        no1[2] = new ArrayExample(10);
        no1[3] = new ArrayExample(10);
        no1[4] = new ArrayExample(10);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(no1));
    }
}

class ArrayExample {
    // use same class contents as your original post
}
```

Here is output from running this updated code:

```
[6474373150570442153, 27524825597078735826, 58127219204026904839, 90611080549351937198, 6503557163540938849]
```

Another option for setting your array contents would be using this one-liner:

```
Arrays.setAll(no1, k -> new ArrayExample(10));
```